# Laravel Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ' public' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

Tags: laravel, syntax-error

I must be blind or something, my Controller is not behaving as expected but I don't see anything wrong in my code. I get "syntax error, unexpected '   public' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)", right after declaring "class ContactController extends Controller {"

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\ContactUS;

class ContactController extends Controller {
   /**
    * Show the application dashboard.
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
   public function index(Request $request)
   {
       return view('contactUS');
   }
}
```

If I do this:

```
class ContactController extends Controller {
 function index(Request $request){
       return view('contactUS');
   }
}
```

I get "unexpected '   function' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)"

My model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ContactUS extends Model
{
    public $table = 'contactus';
    public $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'message'];
}
```

My route:

```
Route::get('contact', [
    'as'    => 'contact-us',
    'uses'  => 'ContactController@index'
]);
```

Comment: Does it say in which line the error occures? Which PHP/Laravel version are you using, maybe you are using an old interpreter with a new Laravel version that uses syntax unknown to PHP?

Comment: @TobiasK just updated the question, it's right after declaring the class. It's a controller just like all other controllers in my project, I must have a typo somewhere... or forgot something....

Comment: your controller is fine, you sure it's your controller? can i see whoops output ?

Comment: @SupunPraneeth the error is all I get as response, I do notice lots of spaces (tabs) before the word "public". Laravel seems to handle the file totaly the wrong way. Propably the error comes from somewhere else but I have no idea what it could be.

Comment: What is in your base class? Add anything there?

Comment: @OneLiner I don't know what the problem exactly was. But apparently copying code from the web didn't went as expected. I've already tried showing all invisible characters and didn't found anything weird. But what helped for me was copying a working Controller to a new one and I've added line by line from the original file. Nothing broke... and worked right away... Weird huh

Comment: That is strange. Tabs spaces and newlines dont affect PHP. Windows has at least one different cntrl char I believe. Maybe that did it. Vim makes it easy to see ctrl chars btw.

Comment: What editor were you using?

Comment: @Polaris nothing fancy... Notepad++